# How to redirect the authentication request of a particular federated domain in Azure from azure to on-premise AD via ADFS server

Tags: azure-active-directory

In our current, authentication request from azure to on-premise AD goes via a Optimal IDM tool (this is 3rd party tool which is being used for account synchronization and federation service). Now our requirement is to redirect the authentication request of a particular federated domain in Azure from azure to on-premise AD via ADFS server (instead of Optimal IDM tool).

kindly provide the steps/commands to achieve this.

Thanks
Sunil Sharma

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD Connect would be your best bet now.

Detailed guidance is available here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnectfed-whatis

Comment: Thanks for help...I gone through the above link but didn't find any information on how to redirect the authentication request of a particular federated domain in Azure (out of total 170 domains) from azure to on-premise AD via ADFS server. Rest 169 federated domains should continue using the Optimal IDM tool for authentication redirection to on-premise AD.